# How to use bower_component with typeScript in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bower, predix

I am in a problem with using bower components in typeScript. Is it possible use bower_components. I import bower_component in index.html but it's not import for other .html. Can you please give solution for this issue.

This import line in index.html.

```
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/...html" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009301/how-to-use-a-bower-component-in-a-angular-2-project/41011078#41011078

Comment: can you specify what you are trying to import?

Comment: I try to import predix-ui component. It is under bower_component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your errors if it is stating to add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA then you can add this to your AppModule

`schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ HeaderComponent ],
    imports: [ RouterModule, CommonModule, FormsModule ],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: How do I add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to my project. I am new to typescript So can you show me example. Thanks